# Msgbox doesn't popup vb.net (VS2012)

Tags: vb.net, msgbox

I have this code for onclick event and the msgbox doesn't popup. It will be blinking on the status bar waiting to be clicked. Why doesn't it popup.

```
Dim msg As String = "Patron " & PatName & " has been added to the system?" & vbCrLf
        msg = msg + "Do you want to add incident to this patron?"
Dim title As String = "Patron addition confirmation"

 Dim MsgResponse As String = MsgBox(msg, MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, title)

    If MsgResponse = 1 Then
            Response.Redirect("~/AddInciInfo.aspx?value1=" & PassParameters, False)
    Else
            Me.Dispose()
            Response.Redirect("~/SearchPatron.aspx", False)
    End If
```

Comment: You can't do that.  You need to understand the difference between server-side code and client-side code.

Comment: @SLaks - This is client-side code right? Does confirmbutton extender has this kind of functionality?

Comment: No.  C# code runs on the **server**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MsgBox` is a function for *client-side* WinForms or WPF code. You are writing *server-side* ASP.NET code. With ASP.NET, there is no simple method to show a message box to the end user.

There are, however, alternatives: You can use

- client-side JavaScript to show a message box to the user or
- use the [ModalPopup control](http://www.asp.net/AjaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx) from the ASP.NET Ajax Library, which creates a HTML/JavaScript control that looks similar to a Windows message box.

Comment: What's the difference between confirm button extender and modalpopup control?

Comment: @Nita: `ConfirmButton` shows a simple message box with some text and OK/Cancel-Buttons. `ModalPopup` shows arbitrary HTML content.